# Wireless working, but no X. Want to reinstall. How to save wifi configuration, while reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, nvidia, reinstalling

I've tried Ubuntu and was pleasantly surprised that it is so much better now. I had only two problems to solve upfront. I had no wireless and only the nouveau video drivers. I've installed (Thanks to some help) the wifi drivers and even tried to install nvidia. I ended up with working wireless, but no X. I've made a backup too late, so I now have a clonezilla  img of a disk with working wi-fi, but no graphics. My friend ran out of patience in the process so I am alone in the woods now.

I decided to reinstall Ubuntu from live dvd, because it seems easier. So, do I just copy ath10k/2.1.../... to get my wifi running and then install proper tardy nvidia driver by software update, or There are additional steps that I should take?

Your help would be very helpful.
Thank you,
A

Comment: Assuming that is all you did to get the card working; that is, install firmware in /lib/firmware/ath10k, then yes, your assumption is correct. Without further details, such as the Ubuntu version you intend to install and the exact identity of your wireless card, `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` it is impossible to say for certain.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer N1525 Wireless-AC [1a56:1525]
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

Comment: what does this 0280 mean? or -nnk

Comment: `lspci` means, as you might guess, 'list all PCI devices.' -nn means to show the PCI vendor and device codes as both numbers and names. -k means to show the driver in use. Finally, PCI wireless devices are always of the class 0280. This allows us to see only the wireless device, as you see, rather than a lengthy listing of *all* PCI devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 15.10 and, presumably, newer, your wireless device uses the driver `ath10k_pci`, as you see:

> Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e]
>   (rev 20) Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer N1525 Wireless-AC
>   [1a56:1525] Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

The required firmware is not yet included by default. You were able to find and download it to get your device working. I suggest you back up the entire contents of `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174`. After the reinstall, restore it and your wireless should be working.